# Get the AuditAction's Username property in derived AuditDataProvider

Tags: c#, audit.net

I am using Audit.Net and Audit.MVC 14.2.2.0. Great framework!

I have extended the AuditDataProvider:

```
 public class SQLAuditDataProvider : AuditDataProvider
```

In that class, I would like to get hold of the auditEvent's Action object, so that I can log the Username. (I don't want the Environment's username, although I can get it.) 
When I debug, I can see that Action property, but when I try to type it, I get a compile time error.

I could store it as a CustomField in the HomeController, but it would be preferable simply to get it in the SQLAuditDataProvider.

I'm probably doing something stupid, but what have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `AuditEvent` as `AuditEventMvcAction` and then access the `Action` property:

```
var action = (auditEvent as AuditEventMvcAction).Action;
```

Or you can use the convenient extension method:

```
using Audit.Mvc;

var action = auditEvent.GetMvcAuditAction();

// Or from the audit scope
var action = auditScope.GetMvcAuditAction();
```